# "Your device isn't compatiable with this version.. play store

Tags: android, store, playback

Today I published an app but he message show in play store " "Your device isn't compatible with this version.. play store" so please tell me what I do next.

Comment: Add your module level `build.gradle` and also your device information

Comment: change minSdkVersion in Build Gradle

Comment: I use this        minSdkVersion 16
                     targetSdkVersion 29   please tell how much use min and max Version

Comment: did you have any hardware permission in your app?
Check your manifest.xml file if you have added hardware camera `<uses-feature>` and made it required true, then this type of issue happens.

Comment: yes, This    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />

Comment: add `required = "false"` in that <uses-feature> it will solved your issue.

Comment: Google play console show ------  0 supported by this app                                    but I did test this app many devices before publish in play store

Comment: yes, this issue not happens in devices. this issue happens on device compatibility on play console. because as per play console many of has no hardware camera feature enabled so that will not be considered compatible devices.

Just try  `required = "false"` in that `<uses-feature>` and republish app on play store. 
I already faced the same issue

Comment: Ok, I will try.  Thank you

Comment: Thanks, sir, It's working